# React useEffect runs after subsequent renders although Redux-dependency has not changed

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, redux, react-router, react-hooks

I have a React-function-component with an expensive side-effect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    doExpensiveSideEffect(reduxProp);
  }, [reduxProp]);
```

`reduxProp` is a property that gets served from the outside via a Redux-connector. For this question, I hope that the exact origin of `reduxProp` does not matter.

My problem is that `doExpensiveSideEffect` runs more often than necessary.

- It runs after the first render, which is fine.
- It runs whenever `reduxProp` got re-assigned, which is also fine.
- However, it also runs after subsequent renders even if `reduxProp` did not change!

This leads to my question:
**How can I ensure that `doExpensiveSideEffect` runs if and only if `reduxProp` got re-assigned, regardless of the number of subsequent renders?**

## EDIT:

It is worth noting that the component is wrapped into a Router-Higher-Order-Component. The routing is controlled by an IonReactRouter-Component. I suppose that IonReactRouter generates multiple instances of the same child-component, which may be the root cause of this issue.

See https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/navigation for more information on IonReactRouter.

Furthermore, `reduxProp` is passed via the `connect`-function of `react-redux`.
In between, a custom "selector" is used to select `reduxProp` from the global AppState.
The following code demonstrates the path from the global AppState to the above-mentioned useEffect:

```
const OuterComponent = withRouter(
  connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps, AppState>(
    (state: AppState, ownProps: OwnProps) => ({
      reduxProp: selectPartOfState(state, ownProps),
    }),
    {}
  )(InnerComponent)
);
```

Now `InnerComponent` receives `reduxProp` in its props and includes the above-mentioned useEffect.

Comment: It looks like `reduxProp` gets re-assigned somewhere in your code

Comment: what is `reduxProp` and how is it passed to this component ?

Comment: If it's a different actual object or array instance, it will cause that useEffect to change. can you show us the code that passes that value into your component (either where it's being called from, or in the connector)

Comment: I have now updated the question with additional information about `reduxProp`

Comment: Checkout the `immer` immutability library. You can use it to make your reduxProp immutable and then only trigger renders when reduxProp changes.

Comment: It's worth adding the code for syncPropWithUrlParam(state, ownProps), you will need to check that you are creating a new object for reduxProp and not mutating the existing value.

Comment: After some debugging, I believe that the issue is not about Hooks/Redux, but about my Routing-Component. I use an IonRouterOutlet component that generates multiple instances of the same child-components. Therefore, the useEffect can trigger multiple times.

Comment: I personally have stopped using any router components for a while. I find these 3rd party libs often bring more trouble than gain.

Comment: I can relate to that. So far, IonRouterOutlet + react-router caused quite a lot of trouble. The only merit I recognize in IonRouterOutlet are the animations.